# How can I send two values from bluetoothSPP in android to arduino?

Tags: android, arduino

This is my code.

I wanna receive two values in Arduino from android app.

I can receive one value but I can't two values.

Here is my code.

I wanna send two values with Bluetooth.send().

**How can I do that?**

I use bluetoothSPP in android studio.

I wanna receive Go ,Back, Right, Left and seconds in arduino.

so If i receive Go and 2sec, my arduino rc car go for 2 sec.

```
//Arduino code
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

SoftwareSerial BT(blueTx,blueRx);
Servo servo;
char input1;
char input2;

void loop() {
  if(BT.available()){
    if(Serial.available()){
      Serial.println("------");
      Serial.println(BT.read());
    }   
    
    input1 = BT.read();
    input2 = BT.read();   
  }
 }

// Android code , i use bluetoothSPP and send method

blockStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!list.isEmpty()) {
                        delayHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                while(!list.isEmpty()) {
                                    String blockName = list.get(0);
                                    num1 = inputNum.getText().toString();
                                    list.remove(0);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    if (blockName == "GO") {
                                        Bluetooth.send("G", true);
                                        Bluetooth.send(num1, true);
                                    } else if (blockName == "BACK") {
                                        Bluetooth.send("K", true);
                                        Bluetooth.send(num1, true);
                                    } else if (blockName == "LEFT") {
                                        Bluetooth.send("L", true);
                                        Bluetooth.send(num1, true);
                                    } else if (blockName == "RIGHT") {
                                        Bluetooth.send("R", true);
                                        Bluetooth.send(num1, true);
                                    }
//                                    inputNum.setText(null);
                                }
                            }
                        }, 10);

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem in the problem , though I did'nt use bluetooth spp , but give this a shot , try to send byte array in `send`
I designed my input like a,b and convert this to byte array , in your case send it like G/K/L/R`,`num1 see the comma added , to convert this to byte array use `getBytes()` , in aurdino do the following :

```
void loop() {

if(Serial.available()){
  int available = Serial.available();
  for(int i=0; i< available; i++){
  char a = Serial.read();
 
  if(i < 1){ 
  input1 = a;
   }
  if(i > 1){
  int c =(int)a - 48;
    input2 *= 10;
    input2  +=  c;
  }
   
  }
}
```

Explanation skip comma which is second character(1) , first character is normal so add it to input1 , second one is number so extract ascii values starts from 48 and get the number from it.Input2 is of type `int` with initial value of 0 , Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you. I try to use Bluetooth.send(("G,"+num1).getBytes(), true); instead of   Bluetooth.send("G", true); , Bluetooth.send(num1, true);.  This is right?

Comment: @seungwan yes if num1 is a string

Comment: I was just wondering if you could check my full code? I think It can't be read in arduino

Comment: @seungwan try false instead of true